# Couchdb doesn't starts on Ubuntu hardy 8.04

Tags: ubuntu, couchdb

I have installed couchdb and its dependencies, all built from sources. Now whenever I issue command couchdb, it says

```
{"init terminating in do_boot",{undef,[{couch,start,[]},{init,start_it,1},{init,start_em,1}]}}
```

How to fix this?

Comment: I know this is more of serverfault question. Has posted there too, but I need a quick fix..

Comment: Try following statement on command prompt `Curl -X GET http://127.0.0.1:5984/_all_dbs`

Comment: Couchdb doesn't start at all.. so no response from the couchdb

Comment: have you checked /var/log/syslog and /var/log/daemon.log? Likely your config is borked. You could try removing the configs and `apt-get install --reinstall couchdb`

Comment: @sehe: I couldn't install it using `apt-get`. What should I do for it?

Comment: @Pravin http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Installing_on_Ubuntu; not so sure that Hardy included it. Hardy desktop already [end-of-lifed months](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases) ago; granted the server edition will be supported till April 2013 (!)

Comment: Very first line says:
_Newer versions of Ubuntu have CouchDB included in their respective software repositories_

Answer (score 2):

If you're building couchdb from sources, I would suggest using [build-couchdb](https://github.com/iriscouch/build-couchdb) tool from IrisCouch. Works perfectly and lets you run multiple couches even of differect versions at the same time.